# Why 10.333333 | 0 = 10 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how JavaScript evaluates the following expression:

`10.333333 | 0 === 10`

Is it because of bitwise ORing ignores the decimal part?

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript bitwise operators all work by converting their operands to 32-bit integers. The operation is performed and the result is converted back to a (floating point) number.